# Behavior of Non-standard attribute "capture" in input type=file tag in Android

Tags: android, html-input

I try to use the following to obtain image from Android phones:

```
<input type="file" name="file_camera" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
```

- Android 2.x: the `capture` attribute is ignored, and Gallery & File Manager applications are allowed to choose from.
- Android 4.x: the `capture` attribute is respected, and Camera applications are allowed to choose from.

If the attribute is absent ( `<input type="file" name="file_camera" accept="image/*" />` ), here are the results:

- Android 2.x: only Gallery & File Manager applications are allowed to choose from
- Android 4.x: Camera, Gallery & File Manager applications are allowed to choose from

How can I have camera in Android 2.x ? Also, what are the other values of the `capture` attribute?

Note:

- Default browser is used. Chrome has the same results.
- In Firefox, Android 2.x & 4.x can choose from Camera, Gallery & File Manager applications.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML file input control with capture and accept attributes works wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523544/html-file-input-control-with-capture-and-accept-attributes-works-wrong)

Comment: @Pinal your question is newer than mine, thus your question is a duplicate instead of mine.

Answer (score 0):

On low-level you capture images by android.media.CameraProfile class which was implemented in Android API lvl 8 (Android 2.2+)

I think Mobile Safari 4(default browser) didn't implement capture, because MS v4 is available on Android 2.0+(API level 5+) and can't to do it.

Firefox is a single low-level app, it can be updated from one API level to other. Maximum API level for Android 2.x.x is 10.

And don't forget Mobile Safari use Webkit, FF - Gecko.