# What is the difference between capture="user" and capture="camera" in input type file tag?

Tags: html, camera, html-input

There is no `capture="camera"` attribute for `input type="file"` tag [in official w3.org documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/).

Ironically on so many places I found `capture="camera"` is used. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916566/html5-input-type-file-accept-image-capture-camera-display-as-image-rat) or [here](https://addpipe.com/html-media-capture-demo/) or [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) and so many other places.

Not a single tutorial with `capture="user"`. Why is that?

Is there any major difference between `capture="user"` and `capture="camera"`?

Can you please also mention device compatibility for `capture="user"` and `capture="camera"`? I couldn't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`capture="camera"` is deprecated in the HTML 5.1 spec.

The capture attributes keywords are `user` and `environment` which relate to front and rear facing cameras respectively.

In addition, there is a third state, the implementation-specific state.

The missing value default is the implementation-specific state. The invalid value default is also the implementation-specific state.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/#dom-htmlinputelement-capture)

Answer (score 0):

May be to take a picture using the device's user-facing camera,using an HTML form is

```
<input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" capture="user">
```

and by default/ normal care using camera to get picture using an HTML form is

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="capture" capture="camera">
```