# Azure Static Websites feature (preview): uploading files

Tags: azure-storage

Testing the new Azure Static Websites feature: I tried it out, uploaded a file via [html5 Mobile Device Camera Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916566/html5-input-type-file-accept-image-capture-camera-display-as-image-rat) and now I can't find it? Where do uploads go? Do I need to set up a public access or similar? Is there a "Kudu" access? Thanks for a tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where do uploads go?

If you upload file upload file to your website, you could access it in the `$web` container in your storage account. Also, the uploaded file can be viewed in a web browser at the corresponding web endpoint like`https://yourstorage.zxx.web.core.windows.net/xxx.xxx`.

> Do I need to set up a public access or similar?

No, you needn't. The web service endpoint always allows anonymous read access, returns formatted HTML pages in response to service errors, and allows only object read operations.

> Is there a "Kudu" access?

If you use Azure Static Websites feature, your websites are all based on azure storage, so there is not a Kudu access, I think you could try to use **Storage Explorer (preview)** in the portal.

For more details about Azure Static Websites feature, refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website).