# input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" not working for mobile

Tags: android, html, forms, mobile

I've got a simple form that uploads some basic info and an image to my formtools database. It works perfectly on desktop but not on mobile. On my Android phone when I test it it asks me to select the camera or file browser I have tried both camera and file browser and I take a picure / upload an image which it seems to do then loads the thank you page, but when I go the the form tools database the image has not been uploaded.

Anyone know why this isn't working?

here's the form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="competitionform" class="uniForm cmxform" name="competitionform" method="post" action="/formtools/process.php">
<input type="hidden" name="form_tools_form_id" value="110" />
<header>
<h2>Upload your image</h2>
</header>
<label>Your Name </label>
<input width="100px;" type="text" placeholder=" " name="name" />
<label>Your Email </label>
<input type="text" placeholder=" " name="email" />             <
<label for="file">Upload Selfie</label>
<input type="file" name="uploadselfie"/>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Upload Selfie" />
</form>
```

I've also tried adding

```
accept="image/*" capture="camera"
```

to the input which opens the camera lets you take a picture then loads the thank you page but again no image is uploaded to the formtools database.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem, any luck with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML file input control with capture and accept attributes works wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523544/html-file-input-control-with-capture-and-accept-attributes-works-wrong)

Answer (score -2):

`<form>` with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` can only upload pic/files and so on .It can't send other input which type is text to the database.

This point, you must set two forms, one for `input type=text`, another for `input type=file`.