# Cannot get file input to work on Android browser

Tags: android, html, file-upload

I'm trying to implement a functionally where the user uploads a photo from their mobile device.

Works on most browser but I can't get it to do anything on Android.

Even with the most basic form content like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="test-file" value="Photo"  accept="image/*" capture />
</form>
```

Nothing happens. The button seems to respond in the sense that it shows it's been clicked but the user isn't prompted to do anything.

I did find a few write ups about it but nothing works. For instance, in [this article from Dev.Opera](https://dev.opera.com/articles/media-capture-in-mobile-browsers/), none of the demos work.

Is there a way to prompt the user for file uploads on Android?

I'm on Android 4.4.2 (through BrowserStack)

**Edit:** Strangely enough it works in a 4.3 Android (Galaxy S4 on BrowserStack), but not in 4.4 :/

**Edit 2:** Seems to work on some other versions. I've tried it on a device with 4.2.1 and another one with 4.4.2 and these worked.

Comment: Maybe try leaving off the capture tag. [There's a nice survey testing this compatibility in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523544/html-file-input-control-with-capture-and-accept-attributes-works-wrong).