# PHP file upload via FTP - Doesn't work with Android camera

Tags: php, android, camera

I'm have a little form which allows file upload using PHP. The form works well using Mac, Windows and iOS, but I'm having problems with Android:

- If I select a picture from the phone and upload it >> works.
- If I select "camera", take the picture and send it, the file somehow gets
  lost. Same if I take the picture first and upload it afterwards. I tried this with 2 different Android phones, same problem.

**print_r($_FILES) results in:**

```
Array (
    [Photo] => Array (
        [name] => 14670896179861993968797.jpg
        [type] =>
        [tmp_name] =>
        [error] => 1
        [size] => 0
    )
)
```

**My PHP code [ftp login details hidden using "XXX"]:**

```
$file = $_FILES["Photo"]["name"];
$file_ext = substr( $file, strrpos( $file, '.' )+1 );
$tmp_file = $_FILES["Photo"]["tmp_name"];
$folder = "public_html/itcma/slips/";

$conn_id = ftp_connect("XXX");
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, "XXX", "XXX");
ftp_put($conn_id, $folder.$file, $tmp_file , FTP_BINARY);
ftp_rename ($conn_id, $folder.$file, $folder.$_GET["id"].".".$file_ext);
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

**My form [shortened]:**

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="upload" id="upload">
<input class="form-control" type="file" name="Photo"></input>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Upload payment slip"/>
</form>
```

Any idea why it works in most cases, but NOT if uploading directly from camera? I tried *accept="image/*" capture="camera"* inside the file input already, which opens directly the camera. Same problem.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: P.S.: "File gets lost" means that no file gets uploaded. If I echo $tmp_file there is no value as well.

Comment: Versions?  This is a good read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523544/html-file-input-control-with-capture-and-accept-attributes-works-wrong  Specs have changed some over last years.