# HTML + JQUERY - Input type file added dynamically not work attribute capture = 'camera' on mobile

Tags: android, jquery, html, file, input

I have the next div:

```
<div id="divLlenarImgs">
  <input type="file" class="img" name="img[]" accept="image/*" capture="camera"/>
</div>
```

When I run my web site in a mobile (android or iphone) and click on that input, the camera is shown by the attribute *capture*.

But when I add more inputs type file dynamically their **attribute *capture* stops to work**. The first input always, but the next added inputs don't.

Is there any reason for this to happen?

I add the next inputs exactly like the first one. And I have tried many different browsers: Safari, Chrome, Firefox and Android default browser.

**EDIT**:

Only work ALL inputs using Chrome for Android.

Comment: What kind of accept type do you add?

Comment: Sorry, edit, attribute capture.

Comment: ok, But still what input files do you add?

Comment: I add input type file with the same attributes and values, exactly like that one.

Comment: I think the answer you are looking fir is found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523544/html-file-input-control-with-capture-and-accept-attributes-works-wrong)