# Force <input type="file"> to open gallery in mobile

Tags: asp.net, html

I want to make my input to only accept files from gallery instead of allowing the user to open the camera.
How can I achieve it?

**ASP.NET**

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="filGallery" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" />
```

**HTML 5**

```
<input type="file" id="filGallery" multiple="multiple" />
```

The behaviour I want is similar to the one found in iOS 8 or less, where input with multiple files enabled couldn't open the camera

Comment: This link may helpful https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp

Comment: I tried to put `accept=".pdf"` but it still asks if I want to upload from camera

Comment: Another http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832930/html-input-file-accept-attribute-file-type-csv

Comment: The question does not addresses the mobile gallery.

Answer (score 14):

I don't think there is a way to force using gallery - current trend is more on using camera (and suggesting using front or back) rather than disabling it.

However, there is a similar question on SO (but focus on type of capture) where that answerer has pointed to some ways of input attribute you may try out:

original SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40512470/2564920

More detail test he has done regard to the mobile capture: https://addpipe.com/blog/correct-syntax-html-media-capture/

A test page which you can try out: https://addpipe.com/html-media-capture-demo/

specifically one setting which is

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="filesystem">
```

looks promising - but probably won't work (since this syntax is deprecated and capture attribute in newer spec is used to say you want to use camera - choosing between front or back camera [source](https://w3c.github.io/html-media-capture/#the-capture-attribute))

Comment: Yeah, didn't work.. Well, I hope the spec changes, would be good to have a way to do it... Thanks anyway, +1

Answer (score 1):

just use simple method to open gallery in mobile

```
  <input type="file" id="fileProfile2" name="fileProfile2"  accept="image/png,image/jpeg" capture="filesystem">
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The 'accept' attribute that you provided is only stating that png and jpeg are the file types accepted.

Comment: @TrayFleary It worked on my side please check yours.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Accept is just a limitation on mime-types allowed, but device is opening system pop-up and gives the option to choose camera as well