# Who do I open the gallery on Android with the file input?

Tags: html, mobile, input

How can I open the gallery on my android device with html5?

I'v tried with  `accept="image/*"` but this didn't worked

```
<input type='file' name='image' accept="image/*">
```

-- Update Juli 2021 --

The issue stil exist and I have not found a way to solve the problem.

Comment: does any of this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43059751/5378743) work?

Comment: No one of them worked

Comment: So i guess you are out of luck.

Comment: humm, this issue still exists. cannot enter to gallery mode