# Disable camera option through html input element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, file-io

I've been looking for a way to disable the 'take a photo' option upon opening the mobile dialog of an input element on mobile devices. My goal is to only allow users to choose pictures from their camera rolls or their device's file system, and to eliminate the camera option completely.

Is this possible? I could not find any input element attribute that would let me do this

Comment: Very likely impossible

Comment: This article may help: [HTML file input control with capture and accept attributes works wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21523544/3113485)